# Beautiful Soup: Cannot Return 'p' Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Python. I have written a piece of code that downloads letters from a website. I want to iterate through each URL in `EachLetter` and return only the text in `p` where the `class` is  `LETTER selectionShareable`. I would like to be able to print the letter that is returned from `EachLetter` with it's correct title, I think I can use `zip` to achieve this. Any help appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
import time
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import urllib
from datetime import datetime
import itertools

# Starts Measuring the Time
start_time = time.time()
# Start Message
print("Program is Starting...")

# The URL for the response
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/letters")
# Making the Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')

# Finding the 'divs'
divs = soup.find('div', {"class": "row sectionteaser"})
letters = {}
i=0

# Finding only the letters with the most recent date
for div in divs:
    if type(div) is bs4.element.Tag:
        i+=1
        letters[i] = [datetime.strptime(div.find('li', {'class': 'last first date'}).string,"%B %d, %Y"), div.find('a', {'class': 'gtm-event'})['href']]

newestdate = datetime(1900, 1, 1)


for letter in letters.items():
    if newestdate < letter[1][0]:
        newestdate = letter[1][0]


newestletters = []

for letter in letters.items():
    if letter[1][0] == newestdate:
        newestletters.append(letter[1][1])


for new in newestletters:
    ITurl = "https://www.irishtimes.com"
    EachLetter = ITurl + new


    response1 = urllib.request.urlopen(EachLetter)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response1, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.text)
    for each in EachLetter:
        letters_content = soup.findAll('div', {'class': "article_bodycopy"})
    for letter in letters_content:
        print(letter.find('p', {'class': "LETTER selectionShareable"}).get_text)


print("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "seconds to run")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this:

```
letter.find('p', {'class': "LETTER selectionShareable"})
```

sometimes returns None.

If you change the latter part of your program to:

```
for each in EachLetter:
    letters_content = soup.findAll('div', {'class': "article_bodycopy"})

    for letter in letters_content:
        found_letter = letter.find('p', {'class': "LETTER selectionShareable"})
        if found_letter:
            print(found_letter.get_text)
```

it should print out what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the latter part to what you have written and it didn't return anything at all, any ideas?